# Как отобразить на форме содержимое HTML-документа?

Tags: c#, yandex-maps-api

На форме `WebBrowser` накинут. Пишу следующее:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\traffic_control.html");
```

Только вот пишет:

> Не удается отобразить страницу.

Закинул на диск C.

И ещё в документе было указано

> Если вы используете API локально, то в URL ресурса необходимо
>   указывать протокол в стандартном виде (http://...)

[API Карт / JavaScript API / Элемент управления "Пробки"](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/traffic_control)

Comment: 1. попробуйте путь вроде ftp://c:\traffic_control.html

Comment: 2. у контрола webBrowser есть свойство Document, ему можно присвоить загруженный через File.ReadAllLines

Comment: 1 - извиняюсь, путь: file://c:\traffic_control.html

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\\traffic_control.html" ну или @"C:\traffic_control.html"
```